# Highcharts: Dynamically append a point to Scatterplot permanently

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot

For Highcharts, I am trying to append a point to Scatterplot dynamically with the following code:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(50 * (i % 3), true, false);
```

However, there are two issues with this code above.

With this setting as above, I can append new points without having my old points disappear - which is exactly what I want. BUT, as I append more and more points, the older points don't "shift" off from the chart.

The solution to shift off older points from the chart is this:

```
chart.series[0].addPoint(50 * (i % 3), true, true);
```

But, that doesn't let me keep the most recent points on the chart - it immediately removes ALL the older points when adding the new one.

Is there a way, how I can add more points dynamically to the scatterplot, keeping the recent points, but shifting off the older points?

http://jsfiddle.net/bluechips23/2ztfbn3w/

**EDIT: Solution below in the new reply**

Comment: What do you mean by shift off? Do you want to remove one point from the old ones when adding one new point?

Comment: What is the limit where points are old or not?

Comment: I solved this issue. It was a stupid little thing on my part. I described my solution in my EDIT above.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than loading random data at the beginning, you can set a clause in your `addPoint()` function to only shift if there are a certain number of data points already in the series.

Something like:

```
(chart.series[0].data.length >= minData ? true : false)
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/2ztfbn3w/4/